# unable to locate ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've purchased the ROS book [Programming Robots with ROS](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024736.do) to help me understand how i can controll the robot i've built.  I was having trouble setting up ROS to work on my ubuntu laptop so i downloaded a pre-setup [virtual machine from nortrix](https://nootrix.com/downloads/#RosVM).  I'm also getting the same issue on the virtual machine, the book says i need to setup the simulation stack, when i do get the follow error :

E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator

How can i move forward on this problem.  I've seen there is a github page for it, do i just clone it ? https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_simulator

Also when i run "sudo apt-get update"  i get :

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease
  
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                                  
  
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty InRelease                              
  
Err http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release.gpg                      
  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err http://packages.ros.org trusty InRelease
  
Err http://packages.ros.org trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'packages.ros.org'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
  
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease
  
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease
  
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'extras.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'packages.ros.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My source files are :

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318446/unable-to-locate-ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator/) by [resolver101757](https://answers.ros.org/users/40406/resolver101757/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it seems that the package is not installed, try to install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator
```

---

Originally posted by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) with karma: 146 on 2019-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [resolver101757](https://answers.ros.org/users/40406/resolver101757/) on 2019-03-13**:
Thanks for the quick reply.  Yeah thats what i was typing to get the response "E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator".  Any other ideas?

**Comment by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) on 2019-03-13**:
oh sorry, i did not know that you were typing the same command. you might need to clone simulator pkgs from github and build it. Do not forget to source your workspace

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-13**:
@mali:

> you might need to clone simulator pkgs from github and build it.

can you clarify why you give this advice?

Building packages from source is very rarely needed, and should really only be a last resort option.

**Comment by [mali](https://answers.ros.org/users/36867/mali/) on 2019-03-13**:
I think it is the second option he has, as he could not install it using sudo apt-get install ...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-13**:
The first thing to do would be to figure out *why* `apt` claims to not be able to find that package for installation. Only if it turns out that it's really unavailable, then we could consider recommending building it from source.

**Comment by [resolver101757](https://answers.ros.org/users/40406/resolver101757/) on 2019-03-13**:
how do i find out why apt cant find the file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-13**:
There is no direct way afaik, but can you install any ROS package using `apt`? Did you run `sudo apt-get update` recently?

**Comment by [resolver101757](https://answers.ros.org/users/40406/resolver101757/) on 2019-03-13**:
thanks for your comments.  I feel we're getting further.  I've added the source and the response from sudo-apt update.  Any ideas from here? your help is appreciated.

**Comment by [resolver101757](https://answers.ros.org/users/40406/resolver101757/) on 2019-03-13**:
ignore my last comment.  the vm had disconnected from the network and DNS screwed up hence not connecting.   Re-initialized the network and ran sudo apt-get update and its getting further, ill post further comments when it gets further.

**Comment by [resolver101757](https://answers.ros.org/users/40406/resolver101757/) on 2019-03-13**:
right this partcular issue is now resolved.  Thanks for your comments.  Once i resolved the networking.  apt-get update updated the catalgoues and i could run sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator successfully.